# Cannot get ajax calls to work with phonegap

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cordova

I am converting my webapp from PHP / HTML to JS/HTML so that it can work with phonegap. I am keeping the php server side files separate and on the server. I am having issues with executing AJAX calls from my local HTML file. When i check the console on chrome, it doesn't show any errors, but the ajax call doesn't return any value either. Ive simplified the issue so that people can easily understand what the problem is.

My JS code is

```
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.betsmart.org/betsmart/models/test.php",
    method: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
        $("#text").html(result);
        }
});
</script>
<h1 id="text"></h1>
</body>
```

My PHP code in test.php is

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
echo "test";
?>
```

The success callback isn't executing. I understand the same origin policy will probably come into play here but i thought that doesn't matter with Phonegap.
Please do let me know where i'm going wrong or an alternate way to do this. If i have to use jsonp, what will be the client side and server side code?
Thanks
Gagan

Comment: For me I get this error in the console. `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.betsmart.org/betsmart/models/test.php. (Reason: CORS request failed)` ( I changed it to https for testing on local machine because I use ssl )

Comment: hmmmm. So is there any other way to do this? Im sure all phonegap apps that use a remote server for any purpose will have a similar issue. So there should be a pretty routine way to do this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough jQuery to guide you with setting up the js function - it will be possible!

Comment: Have you whitelisted the www.betsmart.org url? Does your html file contain the correct Content-Security-Policy meta tag?